# How To Efficiently Check If 10 Variables Are Different

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

I am trying to solve the following math problem using c++:

```
(Each letter represents an individual digit)

  WHITE
+ WATER
-------
 PICNIC
```

So far I have this code to solve the puzzle:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  for (int w = 5; w < 10; w++) {
    for (int h = 0; h < 10; h++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int t = 0; t < 10; t++) {
          for (int e = 0; e < 10; e++) {
            for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
              for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
                for (int p = 0; p < 10; p++) {
                  for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
                    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
                      // I need to check if all the digits are different here
                      if (10000 * w + 1000 * h + 100 * i + 10 * t + e + 10000 * w + 1000 * a + 100 * t + 10 * e + r == 100000 * p + 10000 * i + 1000 * c + 100 * n + 10 * i + c) {
                          cout << "W: " << w << endl;
                          cout << "H: " << h << endl;
                          cout << "I: " << i << endl;
                          cout << "T: " << t << endl;
                          cout << "E: " << e << endl;
                          cout << "A: " << a << endl;
                          cout << "R: " << r << endl;
                          cout << "P: " << p << endl;
                          cout << "C: " << c << endl;
                          cout << "N: " << n << endl;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there some quick test I can run to check if all of the numbers are different (there are 10 different letters so one must be 0, one must be 1, etc.)

**EDIT:**

I tried adding them up and check if equal to 45. I could write another program/method which weeds out the results after the nested loops complete, but is there any better way?

Comment: Add each character to a `std::set` as you go, and check if the next character already exists in the set.

Comment: @NeilKirk Is that going to be fast enough? Because there are going to be a huge number of possible iterations, I don't want it to take forever.

Comment: @NeilKirk: That answers the question as posed in the title, but if you read the code in the question body, it does nothing even remotely like that at all.

Comment: @Puppy: That's because he doesn't know how to do it, so he hasn't written that piece of the code yet.

Comment: Are you sure that brute force is the solution here?

Comment: This is probably (definitely) not the most efficient method for doing this problem. I just got stuck on this and wondered if there was a way to check the integers quickly (in case I had to apply it to some other project).

Comment: Add them all together and see if they add to 45. Not perfect but will weed out most of the false positives, and you can eyeball the rest.

Comment: I tried that and I still got quite a few numbers. Is there any way to only get one result?

Comment: If you're sure each letter must represent a different digit, a better solution would be to generate all possible orderings of { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 } and have a convention that element #0 of an ordering is W, #1 is I, etc. (skipping ones where W < 5 if you want). 10! is a big number, but not nearly as big as 10^10/2.

Comment: The example given was only a few characters long. Unless you are using huge strings, my solution is fast enough.

Comment: You can then do a more expensive test to verify that they are all different. There are many options. For example, put them in an array, sort it, then verify that the array is [0, 1, ..., 9]. Or bucket them and verify that each bucket has only one element.

Comment: To clarify the question. I am not looking for alternate methods to approaching the problem (I know they exist). I am looking for a way to quickly compare 10 integers to see if they are different.

Comment: I do not inderstand why you iterate through p,c and n because those are results. Instead you could compute the result from permutations of "whitear", *determine* pcn from that and check whether, together with i, picnic is the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use the following

```
return ((1 << W)
     | (1 << H)
     | (1 << I)
     | (1 << T)
     | (1 << E)
     | (1 << A)
     | (1 << R)
     | (1 << P)
     | (1 << C)
     | (1 << N))
     == 0x03FF;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for (except for the uppercase letters :)). Do you mind explaining a little bit how it works?

Comment: It is bit-leftshift and bit-or, and it assumes that your number are in range `[0..31]` you may look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation for additional detail

Comment: Hint: 0x3FF is 11 1111 1111 (ten ones) in binary.

Comment: If you ask me, this answer deserves more upvotes for sheer code-fu. It's in essence doing the "use a hashtable to keep track of what you've seen" solution, but it does it super-efficiently by using an `int` as a "hashtable" of bit-sized buckets.

Answer (score 2):

Put all of the digits except the one in `w` in a `std::vector` and use std::next_permutation to iterate through all permutations of them assigning them in order to your letters:

```
std::vector<int> letters(9);

for(int w=5;w!=10;++w)
{
  for(int i=0;i!=9;++i) letters[i] = (i<w) ? i : i+1;

  do
  {
    int h = letters[0];
    int i = letters[1];
    //etc
  }
  while(std::next_permutation(letters.begin(), letters.end()));
}
```

You will then have a valid assignment of digits to letters by construction and won't need to check that they're different, improving performance by a factor of the order of a thousand (exactly how much depends on the average cost of `std::next_permutation`).

**EDIT**

Actually, thinking about it a little more I realise that you can do it even more easily with

```
std::vector<int> letters(10);
letters[0] = 5;
for(int i=0;i!=9;++i) letters[i+1] = (i<5) ? i : i+1;

do
{
  int w = letters[0];
  int h = letters[1];
  int i = letters[2];
  //etc
}
while(std::next_permutation(letters.begin(), letters.end()));
```

since `next_permutation` iterates through permutations in lexicographical order, so `letters[0]` cannot be less than 5.

Comment: This significantly cuts down on the number of iterations (a better solution to the problem) but I still would need a way to compare the integers.

Comment: @cabellicar123: No you wouldn't. The elements of `letters` are guaranteed to be unique, so once you assign them to your variables they *cannot* contain duplicated digits. You do still need to check the sum though.

Comment: Sorry you are right. I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: `Jarod42`'s answer is correct.

The only reason why I'm posting code since I was really surprised to learn that there's a solution with W < 5.  Also, this code takes less than 1 second to run.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

int white(const std::array<int, 10>& x)
{
    // W H I T E A R P C N
    return 10000 * x[0] + 1000 * x[1] + 100 * x[2] + 10 * x[3] + 1 * x[4];
}

int water(const std::array<int, 10>& x)
{
    // W H I T E A R P C N
    return 10000 * x[0] + 1000 * x[5] + 100 * x[3] + 10 * x[4] + 1 * x[6];
}

int picnic(const std::array<int, 10>& x)
{
    // W H I T E A R P C N
    return 100000 * x[7] + 10010 * x[2] + 1001 * x[8] + 100 * x[9];
}

int main(int, char *[])
{
    std::array<int, 10> x;

    std::iota(x.begin(), x.end(), 0);

    do {
        if (white(x) + water(x) == picnic(x)) {
            std::cout << white(x) << " + " << water(x) << " = " << picnic(x) << "\n";
        }
    } while (std::next_permutation(x.begin(), x.end()));

    return 0;
}
```

Note: I'm prepared for downvotes...I just needed a 15-minute break from work.

Comment: Isn't it mathematically impossible to have a solution where `W < 5` because the next highest `4 + 4` even with a `1` carried over would still only yield `9` not enough to get the 6th digit.

Comment: @cabellicar123 P can be 0.

Comment: How very right you are. I had not considered that case. I assume in the original problem however that they intended for `PICNIC` to be a 6 digit number. Also glad I could give you that break and nice speed!

Comment: The code can probably be made an order of magnitude faster by using all permutations of `WHITEAR`, computing the sum of `WHITE + WATER`, and determining if that sum satisfies the `PICNIC` requirement.